# Reduzir imagem e centralizar

Tags: jquery, css3

Pessoal tenho uma imagem que eu trago do banco de dados e coloco numa tag IMG no tamanho de 960px por 480px. Preciso redimensiona-la para 470x160. Preciso que ela seja redimencionada pelo comprimento e a sobra da altura seja recortada, mas tirando do centro para fora. Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso descartar as duas faixas cinzas.

Tem como fazer isto em CSS3 ou JQuery? Se sim como?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola, 
 de um olhada nesse [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b84bund3/) pra ver se era esse o resultado desejado.

este è o codigo:

```js
$("img").hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("img-zoom");
});
```

```css
div{
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:470px;
    height:160px;
}
img{
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
.img-zoom { -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out; -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); -moz-transform: scale(1.2); -o-transform: scale(1.2);     transform: scale(1.2); 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKByS.jpg" alt="img" />
</div>
```

Comment: É isto mesmo. Obrigado

Comment: De nada, espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução seria usar a declaração `transform` na imagem:

```css
div{
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:470px;
    height:160px;
}
img{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKByS.jpg" alt="img" />
</div>
```

Desta forma, tens um contentor para a imagem que define a largura e altura que pretendes obter.

A imagem fica com a largura desse contentor, a declaração `transform` vai centrar a imagem nesse contentor e o topo/fundo da imagem ficam ocultos porque o contentor tem o `overflow` escondido.

Comment: olha deu certo em partes. Quando eu aplico estes 2 css eles funcionam certinho mas eu tenho um evento e hover em JQuery que faz um zoom na imagem ele aplica o seguinte CSS quando se passa o mouse sobre a imagem: `.img-zoom {
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}` e quando sai do hover ativa esta classe: `.transition-zoom {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}`.

Comment: Isto para de funcionar se eu removo o top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); width:100%; ele volta a funcionar. Tem como fazer os 2 rodarem juntos? Obrigado